# how to use .include() method to check the value which is in a json inside array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I want to compare the value of a particular key in my JSON array with new value to check whether the value exists or not.

For example, I have an array:

```
[
    { name: abc, num: 121212 },
    { name: bcd, num: 21212 },
    { name: def, num: 111222 }
]
```

Now a new value comes which I want to check. Does that name already exist? If it does, then I only want to update the number and if not then I want to push the object in the array.

Here is my code:

```
if ((Dnum.num).includes(number)) {
    console.log("inside if");
    console.log(Dnum.indexOf(number)); 
} else {
    Dnum.push({num:number,
        lat:lat,
        lng:lng,
        name:name
    });
}
```

Comment: You can also use `.some()` in this case, see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) for details.

Comment: Your array is completely off, missing " and ,

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

Actually `.includes()` and `.indexOf()` methods won't work with `objects`, they should be used with an array of `strings` or `Numbers` as they use [**strict equality**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Description) to compare the elements and objects can't be compared this way, so you need to implement this logic by yourself.

**Solution:**

You need to check if an object matching the searched `name` already exists in the array, update the `num` value of this object, otherwise if no object matches the searched name, push the new object to the array:

```
if (arr.some(function(obj) {
    return obj.name === searchedVal.name;
  })) {
  arr.forEach(function(el, index) {
    if (el.name === searchedVal.name) {
      el.num += searchedVal.num;
      found = true;
    }
  });
} else {
  arr.push(searchedVal);
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
var arr = [{
  name: "abc",
  num: 121212
}, {
  name: "bcd",
  num: 21212
}, {
  name: "def",
  num: 111222
}];

var searchedVal = {
  name: "abc",
  num: 5
};

if (arr.some(function(obj) {
    return obj.name === searchedVal.name;
  })) {
  arr.forEach(function(el, index) {
    if (el.name === searchedVal.name) {
      el.num += searchedVal.num;
      found = true;
    }
  });

} else {
  arr.push(searchedVal);
}
console.log(arr);
```

If you don't want to use `.some()` method, you can do it this way:

```
var searchedVal = {
  name: "abc",
  num: 5
};
var found = false;
arr.forEach(function(el, index) {
  if (el.name === searchedVal.name) {
    el.num+= searchedVal.num;
    found = true;
  }
});

if (!found) {
  arr.push(searchedVal);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, your problem (if I understand correctly) is that you want to use `includes()` but what you actually want to accomplish doesn't correspond to what the method does. You want to find if there's an object with a certain name in your array already, not if it contains a known element. Something like this:

```
var data = [{name: 'abc', num: 121212}, {name: 'bcd', num: 21212}, {name: 'def', num: 111222}];

function addOrUpdate(newElement, data) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i].name == newElement.name) {
            data[i] = newElement;
            return;
        }
    }
    data.push(newElement);
}

addOrUpdate({name: 'bcd', num: 131313}, data);
console.log(data);
addOrUpdate({name: 'new', num: 131313}, data);
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```js
var res = Dnum.find(function (item) {
  return item.num === number;
});

if (res) {
  console.log("inside if");
  console.log(res);
  res.num = number; 
} else {
Dnum.push({
  num:number,
      lat:lat,
      lng:lng,
      name:name
  });
}
```